# Proof: $\forall\epsilon>0,\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon 0<\frac{1}{2^m}<\epsilon$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $S=\{\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}:m\in\mathbb{N},n\in\mathbb{N}\}$.
>   
> 1. Show that $0$ is a limit point of $S$.
>   
> 2. If $k\in\mathbb{N}$, show that $\frac{1}{2^k}$ is a limit point of $S$.
>   
> 3. Find $S'$, the derived set of $S$.

Proposition: **$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon 0<\frac{1}{2^m}<\epsilon$**

Assuming the proposition is true, my approach is:

**1.** Let $\epsilon>0$.

$\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon0<\frac{1}{2^m}<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$ and $\exists n\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon0<\frac{1}{2^n}<\frac{\epsilon}{3}$

$\Rightarrow \exists m,n\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon 0<\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}<\epsilon\Rightarrow 0-\epsilon<0<\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}<0+\epsilon$

$\because\frac{1}{2^m}+\frac{1}{2^n}\ne0,N'(0,\epsilon)\cap S\ne\phi$ and $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen

$\therefore0\in S'$

**2.** Let $\epsilon>0.$

$\exists p\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon0<\frac{1}{2^p}<\epsilon$

$\Rightarrow\exists p\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon\frac{1}{2^k}-\epsilon<\frac{1}{2^k}<\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^p}<\frac{1}{2^k}+\epsilon$

$\because\frac{1}{2^k}+\frac{1}{2^p}\ne\frac{1}{2^k},N'(\frac{1}{2^k},\epsilon)\cap S\ne\phi$ and $\epsilon$ was arbitrarily chosen

$\therefore\frac{1}{2^k}\in S'$

Assuming the proposition to be true, **3** can be proved too (my solution is long hence, I do not find it necessary to post it here).

> **My Question:**
>   
> How do I prove the proposition? The Archimedean property states that $\forall\epsilon>0\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon0<\frac{1}{m}<\epsilon$.
>   
> How do I use this to conclude $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}\backepsilon0<\frac{1}{2^m}<\epsilon$?

EDIT: What if I write $m=2^{log_2 m}$?

Comment: Use induction to show that $2^m>m$ for $m\in {\mathbb N}$. Then $0<\frac 1{2^m}<\frac 1m$.

Comment: All your observations are correct. Your proofs are worded verbosely, but the ideas are fine. Your edit provides a fine way to prove the proposition, or you can use the idea by Pythagoras. Your idea is probably simpler, but assumes more about the existence of a logarithm.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I understand that the proposition is correct(intuitively) but I needed a worded(?) proof for it, though I have got it from Pythagoras' comment

Comment: @zaira you actually have a proof though. Choose $n$ large enough that $1/n < \epsilon$. Let $m' = \log_2(n)$ so $1/2^{m'}=1/n <\epsilon.$ If you want $m$ to be an integer, just choose $m = \lceil m' \rceil$, where $\lceil \cdot \rceil$ is the ceiling function (returns smallest integer greater than your input). No induction needed, assuming you know logarithms exist (probably easiest to note $e^x$ is defined and increasing on all of $\mathbb R$, so the logarithm will be bijective on the image of $e^x$, i.e. $(0,\infty)$ )

Comment: By using the binomial expansion you get $2^m=(1+1)^m=1+m+\binom{n}2+\ldots\geq1+m>m$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> EDIT: What if I write $m=2^{log_2 m}$?

Well, that depends. What is $\log_2 m$ and what are its properties? You see, the problem is that you seem to use very fundamental properties of numbers. And I'm pretty sure that by using $\log_2$ you will eventually reach circular argument. Like for example you at least need to know that $\log_2$ is an increasing function. Not to mention that you need real numbers to even define $\log_2$.

Anyway, the argument is simple:

> **Lemma:** For any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $2^m>m$.

*Proof.* By induction. This is true for $m=1$ obviously. Now assume that $2^m>m$ for some $m>1$. Since $m>1$ then $2\cdot m>m+1$ and it follows that
$$2^{m+1}=2\cdot 2^m>2\cdot m>m+1$$
which completes the proof. $\Box$

The rest follows from the simple observation that if $0<a<b$ then $0<\frac{1}{b}<\frac{1}{a}$.

Comment: I understood the log proof as mentioned by BrevanEllefsen but it did bother me that I would need to define logarithm in order to use its properties. @Pythagoras suggested using induction for the proof of the lemma, your elaborated proof is agreeably less risky.